# Get a previous installment date

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a function, to which I will pass a **Date** and a **Term** and the result would be the **Date** that is a previous installment of the passed date and term. The following are the examples.

```
Date (In)     |    Term (In)    |    Date (Out)
--------------+-----------------+--------------
22/02/2015    |    Monthly      |    22/03/2015
22/02/2015    |    Quarterly    |    22/02/2015
01/01/2015    |    Monthly      |    01/03/2015
24/03/2015    |    Annually     |    24/03/2015
```

The term value would be either Monthly, Quarterly, Annually. This is the function I currently have, but is not giving me the desired outputs.

```
Public Function getPrevInst(tmpDate As Date, tmpPeriod As String) As Date
    Dim monthDiff As Integer, modVal As Integer, tmpFuncDate As Date, tmpMonDiff As Long

    Select Case tmpPeriod
        Case "Monthly"
            modVal = 1
        Case "Quarterly"
            modVal = 3
        Case Else
            modVal = 12
    End Select

    monthDiff = DateDiff("m", tmpDate, LstDayPrevMnth(Date))

    tmpMonDiff = IIf(monthDiff > 0, monthDiff - (monthDiff Mod modVal), IIf(monthDiff < 0, 0, 1))

    tmpFuncDate = DateAdd("m", tmpMonDiff, tmpDate)

    If tmpFuncDate >= Date Then
        getPrevInst = DateAdd("m", monthDiff, tmpDate)
    Else
        getPrevInst = tmpFuncDate
    End If
End Function

Public Function LstDayPrevMnth(InDate As Date) As Date
    LstDayPrevMnth = DateSerial(Year(InDate), Month(InDate), 0)
End Function
```

My result is (obviously wrong),

```
Date (In)     |    Term (In)    |    Date (Out)
--------------+-----------------+--------------
22/02/2015    |    Monthly      |    22/03/2015
22/02/2015    |    Quarterly    |    22/03/2015
01/01/2015    |    Monthly      |    01/02/2015
24/03/2015    |    Annually     |    24/02/2015
```

If you have a better way of finding the previous installment would also be welcomed. If my code is horribly wrong.

**Layman's term** :

**Peter** borrows a loan from me. He plans to repay it `Monthly`, his first installment being `22 February 2015`. If I open his record, I need to see when was the last payment due/paid. So today (24 March 2015), I would have got his first payment `22 February 2015`, `22 March 2015` (as 22 March was two days ago). So the last installment date is **22 March 2015**.

**Tom** borrows a loan from me. He plans to repay it Monthly, his first installment being `01 January 2015`. If I open his record, I need to see when was the last payment due/paid. So today (24 March 2015), I would have got his first payment `01 January 2015`, `01 February 2015` and `01 March 2015` (as 01 March was 23 days ago). So the last installment date is **01 March 2015**.

**Harry** borrows a loan from me. He plans to repay it Quarterly, his first installment being `22 February 2015`. If I open his record, I need to see when was the last payment due/paid. So today (24 March 2015), I would have got his first payment `22 March 2015` (that is all, the next payment is not due until `22 June 2015` which has not happened yet). So the last installment date is **22 March 2015**.

**NOTE:** Cross posted at : http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=276041

Answer (score 0):

It is a more sensitive than you may think because a month is not "a month".
But - using the Months function below - you can calculate your dates precisely:

```
DateLast = DateAdd("m", Months(DateFirst, Date), DateFirst)
DateLast = DateAdd("m", (Months(DateFirst, Date) \ 3) * 3, DateFirst)
DateLast = DateAdd("m", (Months(DateFirst, Date) \ 12) * 12, DateFirst)
```

Note the integer division with \ .

```
Public Function Months( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full months between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of month counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased stepwise one month from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of months to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2010-03-30. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intMonths As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar months.
  intMonths = DateDiff("m", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a 1 month period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", intMonths, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", -intMonths, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of months to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of months as count of full 1 month periods.
  Months = intMonths - intDiff

End Function
```